# Couldn't create the project directory

Tags: codeblocks

I had a environment error which i resolved but after i resolving the compiler problem, now I can't an open a new project on my codeblocks. I go through the normal procedure to open a new project but it says "couldn't create the project direcory".

Please what can I do to open a new project normally

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.